# Timeout set in web config not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In web config i have set session time out even though my session is reset after 10-15 min

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="525600"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="outerForms" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="525599" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
```

This is what i have set in web.config. Now Value stored in session gets cleared after 10-15 min but user does not get log out.
Sorry if i sound foolish but i am new in asp.net... is it dependent on any other thing?
i am using .net version 4.0

Comment: Did you try changing the IIS Session idle time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098047/asp-net-session-state-not-working-in-web-config-as-well-as-global-asax check this, more people have your same problem...

Comment: Remember in a shared hosting environment, some aspects of the default IIS setup (web.config) "may" override your own custom web.config.

Comment: Thank you chemitaxis.... changing IIS Session idle time sloved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your IIS ideal time Setting. By default it is 20 minutes. You need to increase this value.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by running SQL Server agent service. Make sure that ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions job is enabled